# Swift - UITableView not unhiding

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that I hide and unhide depending on whether or not a variable is empty.

```
if listOfTasks.isEmpty {
    table.hidden = true
} else {
    table.hidden = false
}
```

This is in my `viewDidLoad()` method. Hiding the UITableView works fine, but unhiding it doesn't. [Here](https://github.com/ghostpotato/SE-UILabel-Nil) are my files in case you want to take a look.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad()` is only called once, when the view is loading. You need to unhide `table` whenever the table changes; thus, change

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){   
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
        listOfTasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        table.reloadData()
        if listOfTasks.isEmpty {
            table.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){   
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
        listOfTasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        table.reloadData()
        if listOfTasks.isEmpty {
            table.hidden = true
        } else {
            table.hidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still won't unhide. EDIT: Seems to be that I'm unable to add items... EDIT 2: Found/fixed the unable to edit bug. Still staying hidden.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to add items"? Just add something to `listOfTasks` and check for `listOfTasks.isEmpty` and unhide `table` right after. Make sure you call `reloadData()`.

Comment: I have `table.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear()`.

Comment: Again, that only gets called when the view appears. You need to call it every time you change the data.

Comment: OK. Can I call that from a different view controller?

Comment: Umm, sure. Just pass `table` to the second one. I can't see why you'd need to, though…is the only way to change `listOfTasks` through the second view controller?

Comment: No, but the only place I add items to `listOfTasks` is in a different VC.

Comment: Ok, then put the `listOfTasks.isEmpty` check in `viewWillAppear()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just recreated an example of your code...

```
if listOfTasks.isEmpty {
    table.hidden = true
} else {
    table.hidden = false
}
```

... works fine when placed in inside a "**viewDidAppear**"

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if self.bestRank.isEmpty {
            self.tableView.hidden = true
        } else {
            self.tableView.hidden = false
        }
}
```

When I run the code in Simulator, the Table is hidden when nothing in Array/list but Shows as NOT-hidden when List=populated.

By placing the code in "viewDidAppear" - it will run everytime screen shows, rather than just once under "viewDidLoad".